# Adding a reminder message in git about changes made to sub-tree repositories?

Tags: git, version-control

> "What ends up happening is that the split off folder will live in two
>   repositories:  the existing repo and the one setup as a subtree.  You
>   need to explicitly commit changes to subtree.  This is obviously a
>   mixed blessing.  If you have a repository with a few occasional
>   committers, they can pull the original repository and push as if the
>   subtree didn’t exist.  Then some one on the core team could
>   occasionally push to the subtree."

- [Los Techies, Using git Subtrees To Split a Repository](https://lostechies.com/johnteague/2014/04/04/using-git-subtrees-to-split-a-repository/)

This is great and all, but is there a way to remind people committing that they are using a sub-tree repository, and also need to commit their changes individually in the sub-tree repo?

I'm thinking for instance:

- Placing a message that appears as comments when adding a commit message.
- Placing some sort of message that forces you to press a key, that appears in an on-commit hook.
- Preventing use of the `-m` switch for commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a CI server to keep the subtree repository up-to-date. People in the main project could just keep committing to the main repository without caring too much about the subtree and an automatically triggered CI job would perform the subtree push.

Comment: I'm looking more to remind a developer in the comments when making a commit, or before they add their commit message.